# Introduction to Category Theory without Haskel, Scala or F#

Tags: category-theory

I wan't to get introduced to the fundamental concepts of Category Theory, from a developer's perspective (not a math student), but every single resource I see uses Haskel, Scala, F# or other highly-focused languages that I don't use.

Are there any resources for the rest of us?

Comment: Consider that the (apparently) universal use of those languages in resources on category theory may be because they are well-suited to implementing the fundamentals of the theory in a straightforward way.  Consider that the use of another language, from another paradigm, say C or Java, might mean wading through details of implementation peculiar to one of those languages which would serve only to mask the essentials of the theory.  Your research may be telling you that the right way to understand the fundamentals is through one of those languages.

Comment: That may be true, but for someone fluent in a procedural programming language, it might help them to understand if they start off translating from e.g. Java to Scala.

Answer (score 2):

MIT has an some course material online for [Category Theory for Scientists](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s996-category-theory-for-scientists-spring-2013/index.htm).  There is also a [textbook](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s996-category-theory-for-scientists-spring-2013/textbook/) you can download as well.

Comment: Spivak uses many examples from databases under version control. If you think of a database schema as a category, every time you change the schema you are applying a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor . Category theory allows you to reason between data from all versions of our database.

Answer (score 1):

Pierce's [Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262660717) fits your description. It is in no way tied to any particular programming language.

When learning category theory It's good to have examples to work from. If you don't have examples from mathematics, and you don't have examples from specific programming languages, it might be hard to motivate the subject.